# text_area text formatting

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a webpage for small primary school, where teachers can make a new posts for children parents. Webpage is very simple and I want to keep it simple, but there is a problem with text_area. In the view all written text is in one block, but I want to write some sentences in new line, how I can do this to keep it simple. I don't want to use a rich text editors for that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your view, use `simple_format()` That will display all text as it was typed, with spaces and line breaks.

an example from one of my apps:

```
<div id="report-body">
    <%= simple_format(@report.body) %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `line feed` and `carriage return` to put `new line` in `text area` (i.e) `&#13;&#10;`

For example:

```
<textarea>This is first line. &#13;&#10;</textarea>
```

To add `&#13;&#10;` in text area you need to implement some `javascript` to create keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I get your question correctly; I think it is a question about css. I think you just need to give this property:

```
white-space: pre;
```

in the css for textarea. Then, all white spaces, including carriage return, will appear as they are in the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

wrap your text inside html tags for simplicity, you can also add a simple CSS and style your page as desired.

```
<p> This is your paragraph </p>
<h1> This is your heading </h1>
```

use a `<br>` tag to break line